# Bootstrap checkbox horizontal alignment bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used the basiexample from Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

The problem is that the checkbox is not aligned with the rest of the elements. I tried to set the display attribute to `inline`, but that didn't help.

Any idea why? 
https://jsfiddle.net/6ua8xmce/

Comment: Where did you put the `inline`? Don't see it in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `class="checkbox"` with `class="form-group"`

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello test</h1>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6ua8xmce/1/)

Comment: but doesn't this change label styles also?

Comment: It does change the style but actually this is the right way, because the now label is the same as the others. Marked it as good solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bootflat.css overrides bootstrap's checkbox-label style. it's `padding-left:5px` on the label that contains the checkbox. it needs to be 20px.

```
  padding-left: 20px;
```

if you remove bootflat.css, or set the padding like above, you will get the desired look.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the order of your two CSS dependencies so that `bootflat.css` loads before `bootstrap.min.css`.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6ua8xmce/5/)

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution is to add left padding.

```
padding-left:20px;
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1avaokk/)

Comment: you meant 20px, i guess